# Appending a line to a [section] of a config file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, configuration, samba

I've noticed that some Linux configuration files (e.g. `/etc/samba/smb.conf`) expect you to enter the actual settings (key value pairs) in a particular "section" of the file such as `[global]`.

I'm looking for a terminal tool/command which allows you to append lines to a specific section of a specific configuration file.

Example:

```
configadd FILE SECTION LINE
configadd /etc/samba/smb.conf '[global]' "my new line"
```

Comment: `sed '/\[global\]/a\my new line' /etc/samba/smb.conf`

Comment: First, this command does not **append** the line to the section. Second, it **replaces** [global].

Comment: By the way, `sed 's/^\[global\]/\[global\]\nmy new line/' /etc/samba/smb.conf` wouldn't replace [global] but it wouldn't append the line at the end of the section neither.

Comment: Sure? Do you know any **sed** command except `s`ubstitute?

Comment: I'm very sure about the "appending" part. But actually I was wrong as it comes to the "replacing" part. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Costas You should post that as an answer. I can't think of a better or more elegant solution.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834680/simple-linux-command-line-command-to-modify-an-option-in-a-ini-like-config-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the task by **sed** directly, for example:

```
sed '/^\[global\]/a\my new line' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

NOTE: This is not a solution because such line can be in config already. So firstly you should to test whether is the line present.

Comment: sed -i '/^\[global\]/a\my new line' /etc/samba/smb.conf

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use **ini_file** ansible module

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ini_file_module.html

Example:

```
- name: add line in section "[global]" in specified file
  community.general.ini_file:
    path: /etc/conf/test.ini
    section: global
    option: mynewline
    value: mynewvalue
    mode: '0600'
    backup: yes
```